# Error when using zf2 PHPUnit methods but not standard PHPUnit methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpunit

I upgraded to zf2.3 and am currently attempting to get my unit tests to work again as they did before. Basically, when I use the standard phpunit assertions I get no errors and my tests work as expected:

### Test:

```
public function testGetMemberHomeAction()
{
    $this->assertEmpty(null);
}
```

### Output:

```
PHPUnit 4.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\project\module\Member\test\phpunit.xml

.

Time: 141 ms, Memory: 7.25Mb

←[30;42mOK (1 test, 1 assertion)←[0m
```

However, if I try to use any of the zf2 specific assertions I get an error.

### Test:

```
public function testGetMemberHomeAction()
{
    $this->assertModuleName('Member');
}
```

### Output:

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\project\module\Member\test\phpunit.xml

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getParam() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase.php on line 472
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:426
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:675
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:675
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:753
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestResult.php:686
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:817
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:951
PHP  12. MemberTest\Controller\MemberControllerTest->testGetMemberHomeAction() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php:951
PHP  13. Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase->assertModuleName() C:\wamp\www\project\module\Member\test\MemberTest\Controller\MemberControllerTest.php:57
PHP  14. Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase->getControllerFullClassName() C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractControllerTestCase.php:485
```

### My Bootstrap.php file

```
namespace MemberTest;

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use RuntimeException;

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
chdir(__DIR__);

/**
 * Test bootstrap, for setting up autoloading
 */
class Bootstrap
{
    protected static $serviceManager;
    protected static $config;
    protected static $bootstrap;

    public static function init()
    {
        $zf2ModulePaths =   array(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));

        if (($path = static::findParentPath('vendor')))
        {
            $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
        }
        if (($path = static::findParentPath('module')) !== $zf2ModulePaths[0])
        {
            $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
        }

        static::initAutoloader();

        // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
        $config =   array
            (
                'module_listener_options' => array
                             (
                                 'module_paths' => $zf2ModulePaths,
                             ),
                'modules'             => array
                             (
                                 'Member'
                             )
            );

        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
        $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
        static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public static function chroot()
    {
        $rootPath = dirname(static::findParentPath('module'));
        chdir($rootPath);
    }

    public static function getServiceManager()
    {
        return static::$serviceManager;
    }

    protected static function initAutoloader()
    {
        $vendorPath     =   static::findParentPath('vendor');
        $zf2Path        =   getenv('ZF2_PATH');
        if (!$zf2Path)
        {
            if (defined('ZF2_PATH'))
            {
                $zf2Path    =   ZF2_PATH;
            }
            elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library'))
            {
                $zf2Path    =   $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library';
            }
            elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library'))
            {
                $zf2Path    =   $vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library';
            }
        }

        if (!$zf2Path)
    {
            throw new RuntimeException
            (
                'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or'
                . ' define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'
            );
        }

        if (file_exists($vendorPath . '/autoload.php'))
        {
            include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
        }

        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        AutoloaderFactory::factory( array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
        'autoregister_zf' => true,
        'namespaces' => array
        (
            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
        ),
            ),
        ));
    }

    protected static function findParentPath($path)
    {
        $dir = __DIR__;
        $previousDir = '.';

        while (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $path))
        {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
            if ($previousDir === $dir)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }
}

Bootstrap::init();
Bootstrap::chroot();
```

### My Test Controller

```
namespace MemberTest\Controller;

use MemberTest\Bootstrap;
use Member\Controller\MemberController;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack as HttpRouter;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class MemberControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
protected $controller;
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $routeMatch;
    protected $event;

    public function setUp()
    {
    $serviceManager     = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->controller   = new MemberController();
        $this->request      = new Request();
        $this->routeMatch   = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
        $this->event        = new MvcEvent();

        $config         = $serviceManager->get('Config');
        $routerConfig   = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
        $router         = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);

        $this->event->setRouter($router);
        $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
        $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);

        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include '/../../../../../config/application.config.php'
        );

        parent::setUp();
    }

public function testGetMemberHomeAction()
{
    $this->assertModuleName('Member');
    #$this->assertEmpty(null);
}
}
```

I'm at a loss for figuring out what's wrong. Compounding the issue is that with zf2.1 and the phpunit tutorial there, my phpunit tests worked without a hitch. Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `dispatch` method before asserting module name.

```
public function testGetMemberHomeAction()
{
    $this->dispatch('/your/url');
    $this->assertModuleName('Member');
}
```

Comment: Read the dispatch function. The error I got was because the method assertModuleName gets the Controller class it needs via the method getControllerFullClassName which in turn uses the MVC and URL matching via getRouteMatch. Since there was no route, there was nothing to match. The dispatch method is used to fire up the MVC via the URL which gives you a URL and the MVC. Problem solved. Thanks!!!